# How do I convert code to a syntax-highlighted form that can be pasted (from a clipboard) into Google Docs?

Tags: python, markdown, syntax-highlighting, clipboard

I regularly copy & paste code from websites (C, Python, R, bash, etc.) and store them into Google Docs (in a syntax-highlighted form).  My current method way to do this is to copy the code into a Markdown cell of a Jupyter notebook, for example:

````
```python
[paste code here]
```
````

Next, I would have the Markdown rendered into a syntax-highlighted form, and then I will copy & paste it into Google Docs. I'm looking for a better way to do this.

**Edit 1**: What I have so far is the following code:

````
from tkinter import Tk
import mistune

# Get data from clipboard
w = Tk()
w.withdraw();
clipboard = w.clipboard_get()
w.destroy()

# Convert clipboard data into html
html = mistune.markdown("```python\n" + clipboard + "```")
````

The question now is how do I get the rendered html back into the clipboard into a form that can be cut & paste into Google Docs?
**Note**: I'm fine with other libraries other than `tkinter` and `mistune`, for example `QClipboard` in `PyQt5.QtGui` or `PyObjC`. It is also not a "must" to use the markdown/html route to convert the plain text code into a syntax highlighted form.

**Edit 2**: I found yet another way to do this (but it still requires yet an extra step to copy & paste from the Mac terminal into Google Docs) using [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/).  The following are added to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias syn_py="pbpaste > temp.py && pygmentize temp.py && rm temp.py"
alias syn_c="pbpaste > temp.c && pygmentize temp.c && rm temp.c"
```

Note that on Linux, `pbpaste` / `pbcopy` needs to be replaced by an [appropriate equivalent](https://superuser.com/questions/288320/whats-like-osxs-pbcopy-for-linux).  The settings for the Mac terminal are "Display ANSI colors" and chose the "Basic" theme for "Use Style for 'Copy' command").  Also, I've tried the following, but none of these worked:

```
pbpaste | pygmentize | pbcopy
pbpaste > temp.c && pygmentize temp.c | pbcopy && rm temp.c
```

Comment: Some approaches here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/how-can-i-get-code-syntax-highlighting-in-google-docs

Comment: Store them in a git repository hosted on github or bitbucket or gitlab instead of google docs, where you get syntax highlighting in your browser for free as well as version control?

Comment: The cut & paste methods in the webapps.stackexchange links are not too different from doing a copy & paste into a Jupyter notebook followed by a copy & paste into Google Docs. The Git repository option (assuming it's a public repository) is problematic due to copyright licensing issues--I need an option that works regardless of whether the code posted on a web page is under a MIT/Apache license, is GPL'd, or under "default copyright" (when no copyright agreement is stated).

Comment: I've found another partial solution via pygments. It isn't a complete solution (I still need to copy & paste the terminal output into Google Docs), but its still faster than the Juypter notebook route.